# use target on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

i'm trying to enable the :target on some element, and it seems to work on IE, Firefox, and even Chrome on my phone, but somehow it wont work on my Chrome Desktop. any suggestions?

HTML (deleted the irrelevant code) :

```
    <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
        <a href="#gym">THE GYM</a>
    </nav>

<div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="gym" id="gym"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gym {
    z-index:3;
    position:fixed;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    box-shadow:2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin-bottom:-200px;
    transition: margin-bottom ease 1s;
    -webkit-transition: margin-bottom ease 1s;
    -o-transition: margin-bottom ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: margin-bottom ease 1s;

}

#gym:target {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

By the way, when i tried to do this method with JS, with the .css function, it won't even work...the site is on [boazkerengil.com](http://boazkerengil.com)

Comment: What version of chrome? What's the url in the address bar? Try opening the developer tools, finding the element and seeing if the css properties pane includes the :target styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that anything is broken. It's just a white box that appears, correct? If so, it is working. Here is a screen recording of what happens: http://cl.ly/VWDf. I am using Chrome Mac 34.0.1847.137.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that i needed to update my chrome.. silly me

Comment: No worries! Out of curiosity, why did Chrome need to be updated? It is supposed to auto-update itself.